# Remove ScrollBars from QWebEngineView or QWebEnginePage

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine

Is there a way to remove scrollbars from `QWebEngineView` or can i somehow get access to it's ScrollArea?

With webkit it was as easy as

```
WebView->page()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
WebView->page()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

but i don't see any similar functionality within QWebEngine. I do not even see any scroll area within qwebengine sources.. Is there a something that i'm missing?

Update: I think i can try to force scrollbars disappear from some css settings that are passed with page for chromium

Comment: As far as I can tell, Chromium handles drawing the scrollbars and you'd have to make a custom build of WebEngine if you wanted to modify them in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing css style of the webpage worked. I've used

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

but bad luck for those, who do not have access for css of the webpage you are trying to show the way you want.

Comment: @OzanYukruk I modified webpage itself (i have access to it's code.) To do this through Webengine - it has method that gets you plain text of html source code. Correct style tag and load modified page i guess

Comment: Oh okay, I'm just requesting websites that I don't have access to. So It seems I won't be able to hide the scrollbar

Comment: m_webView>page()>runJavaScript("document.body.style.overflow='hidden';");  this did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Just set `QWebEngineSettings::ShowScrollBars` to false which is introduced in Qt 5.10

See [QWebEngineSettings::WebAttribute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)