# Deactivate scrolling QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qwebkit

In my projects I'm using QWebView exhaustively to display user information in a pleasant way. In order to deactivate scrolling of my QWebView widget I included the following line:

**Qt 4.8**

```
QWebView* webView;

webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Now we switched to Qt 5.8 and there were plenty of changes to consider. Most of them I got ported, but the deactivation of the scrolling is still a mystery to me.

**Qt 5.8**

```
QWebEngineView *webView;
webView->page() // There is not setScrollBarPolicy here???
```

Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: it seems you should deal with underlying css and javascript for each loaded page http://stackoverflow.com/a/32823257/2266412